# Houdini voronoifracture group

Tags: voronoi, houdini

I have a little workflow with fractures and I'm having troubles at the moment of making the fracture apply only to certain group.

[image: Workflow]

Being the wrangle vex:

[image: Wrangle]

[image: Blast]

And then I try to make the voronoifracture to take upon that group:

[image: Voronoi]

The problem is that the model appears grayed out, as if no group were found despite it appears in the spreadsheet:

[image: Viewport]

I'm fairly new to houdini and in the lesson I've been following the fracture takes the group correctly. The lesson is recorded in houdini 16.5 though, and as I'm using 17.0 I'm unsure if the behaviour changed or if I'm doing something wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

Voronoi fracture accepts primitive groups, but you have set a point group. Change your wrangle to run over *primitives* instead of *points*.

Just an aside: your blast is cooperating because it will figure out the group type for you by default.

Comment: @Cyanide this looks like a valid solution to your problem. If it is, will you accept this answer?